# How can I get the address of Java Methods in JVM?

Tags: java, jvm

thank you, as it is other's idea, I delete it

Comment: What is an "address"? It does not have much meaning at Java layer. If you explain why you need this it will be easier to help.

Comment: forget about the address: one of the main reasons which led to design of Java. Every language has some purpose. Java is not a feasible candidate for these kind of programing needs.

Comment: One simple question: why?

Comment: But... what vulnerability? There isn't one.

Comment: @computereasy Java is [immune to buffer overflows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479701/does-java-have-buffer-overflows). Unless you're calling C-language routines you don't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to see the address of a method it is to use certain VM-specific command-line parameters to print the generated native machine code of a method. The addresses are in the disassembly, among other things: https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/PrintAssembly

If you only want to see the code, that's your answer. The addresses themselves don't seem useful though, unless you're debugging the VM itself. You certainly couldn't call them from C like that, as the VM is free to repeatedly re-compile methods and move them about, and it does. (This sounds like a case of the [X-Y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). If you say what you're really trying to accomplish you may get a more useful answer.)